# Brownian motion hitting set of positive density

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

This is motivated by [Showing that Brownian motion will hit sphere with an exact integer distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462114/showing-that-brownian-motion-will-hit-sphere-with-an-exact-integer-distance/4462243#4462243).

The density of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by
$$d(A) = \limsup_{R \to \infty} \frac{\mu(A \cap B_R(0))}{\mu(B_R(0))}.$$
where $B_R(0)$ is the ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin.

Question: if $A$ is open and $d(A) > 0$, is it true that for the Brownian motion $B_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the hitting time $T_A$ to $A$ is finite almost surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. By Fubini's Theorem, there exist   spheres $S(0,R_j)$ with $R_j \to \infty$ such that the surface area of $A \cap S(0,R_j)$ exceeds $d(A)/2$ times the surface area of $S(0,R_j)$. Hence the probability that BM $B$ visits $A \setminus B(0,R)$ exceeds $d(A)/2$ for each $R$. The Blumenthal zero-one law (applied to the BM $\; t \mapsto tB(1/t)$)  then implies that $P(T(A)<\infty)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: Could you point out how do you use Fubini's Theorem to prove that, and how do you apply Bluementhal zero-one law for concluding?